# CLient.timeout execeeded while awaiting header in windows 10 while installing postgress image in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-command

I am new to Docker.

I am encountering below error while executing below command in windows 10

```
    docker-compose up
```

I tried below command and tried to install again but still facing the same error

```
    docker system prune -a
```

[image]

docker-compose.yml

```
    services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres:latest
      container_name: postgres
    environment:
     - "TZ=Europe/Amsterdam"
     - "POSTGRES_USER=docker"
     - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker"
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
```

Comment: Please add errors as text and not pictures of the errors

Comment: @James Z,  I am unable to edit my post.